# Regular expression: how to look ahead/behind through the next 5 Words?

Tags: regex, expression

In the sentence "with the electric current density of 7 A the test arrangement"  I need to check that within 5 words behind or after 7 A stands the word "density". 
So I use smth. like this [0..9]+[Blank]+A. The question is how to use the commands "look ahead" example1(?=example2) and "look behind" example1(?<=example) to check not only the next or previous word, but the next or previous 5 words? are there another possibilies to match that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something can be done with lookahead - definitely not with lookbehind but anyways, regex is not the proper tool to count tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookaheads can be performed with `(?=...)` for positive lookahead, `(?!...)` for negative lookahead. Lookbehind is `(?<...)` or `(?!<...)` However, not all regular expression engines support variable-length lookbehinds, so you may have a problem there.

For the lookahead part, a naïve solution (not accounting for punctuation, words composed of things other than `/w`, etc.) would be:

```
7 A(?=\s+(?:\b\w+\s+){0,4}density)
```

You'll then want to for EITHER the lookahead OR the lookbehind solution.

However, why not just check for: "density" then 0-4 words then 7 A OR 7 A then 0-4 words then "density" without lookaround? Is there a reason you need a zero-width assertion?

That would be something like:

```
(?:density(?:\s+\w+\b){0,4}\s+)(7 A)|(7 A)(?:\s+(?:\b\w+\s+){0,4}density)
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I don't need look ahead/look behind at all. Your solution is exactly what i needed.